# Do I need to use Google cloud platform for my Google Analytics WordPress plugin?

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-compute

I had developed my own custom Google Analytics plugin before some months, now I have got an email from them that .

> Hello, Your Google Cloud Platform project(s):  1)project1 2)project2
>
> has/have been in the billing disabled state for more than 30 days.
>   Since a valid billing account is required for Google Compute Engine,
>   all related Google Compute Engine resources are scheduled to be
>   deleted in as soon as 7 days.

Can you please give me some suggestion on this?
Am I using Google cloud platform which is paid for these plugins, I do not know and is there a way to keep it working with out using this ?

**I do not remember using Google cloud platform or signed up for it during development of the plugin.*

**Got this [The mail was a mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809623/action-required-7-days-left-to-recover-google-compute-engine-resources-in-billi), but there is no good resource that can convince it to be true.**

Answer (score 1):

The email suggests that you don't have an active billing account - that IF there were charges, Google would be unable to charge your current details.

[Update your billing method](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293499#enable-billing) and this should clear.

Comment: Does wordpress analytics plugin needs google platform to work ? and if there is another way with out using this compute engine ?

Comment: Can you link the plugin you're using?

Comment: That is not published it is for my personal use, so now it is on localhost .

Comment: Are you using an API from Google Developers console?

Comment: yes, I am using google developer console.

Comment: I have  also updated the question please check it.